# Why is $\mathbb{Z}/p^{m-n}\mathbb{Z} ≅ p^n\mathbb{Z}/p^m\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Where $m \geq n$?

It's intuitive but I have no reason to justify the interchange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $d\mid n$ then the composition $\Bbb Z\xrightarrow{\times d} d\Bbb Z\to d\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ has kernel $\frac{n}{d}\Bbb Z$ and is onto.

Answer (score 1):

As a variation of Wacka's answer, consider the homomorphism \begin{align}\phi : p^n\Bbb Z &\to \Bbb Z/ p^{m-n}\Bbb Z
\\ p^nk &\longmapsto \overline k  \end{align}

It is surjective, and it has kernel $$\ker\phi=\{p^nk \mid k \equiv 0 \pmod{p^{m-n}}\},$$ but then $k \in \ker\phi \implies k=p^{m-n}j$ for some $j \in \Bbb Z$, so $p^nk=p^n(p^{m-n}j)=p^mj,$ meaning $\ker\phi \subseteq p^m\Bbb Z$.

Then $p^m\Bbb Z \subseteq \ker\phi$ because $p^mh=p^{m-n}(p^nh) \equiv 0 \pmod{p^{m-n}}$

(Then use the first isomorphism theorem.)